# DB2 Query - eliminate maxvalues

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following problem (simplified):

I have a table that contains animals, e.g:

```
ID       Type      Birthday
1        Dog       1.1.2011  
2        Cat       2.1.2009
3        Horse     5.1.2009
4        Cat       10.6.1999
5        Horse     9.3.2006
```

I know that all the animals belong to one "family". From each family I now want to see all the offspring, but I do not want to see the entry for the "founder of the family".

So for the simple sample above I just want to see this:

```
ID       Type      Birthday
2        Cat       2.1.2009
3        Horse     5.1.2009
```

So far I haven't been able to find a way of grouping the entries and then removing the first entry from each group. I was only able to find how to remove specific lines.

Is it even possible to solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @mu is too short: More like `offset 1` per partition, which is not the same as simply `offset 1`, I think. (I mean, `offset` doesn't support partitioning, does it?)

Comment: @AndriyM: I think you're right on the interpretation of the question. Looks like yet another job for OVER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple SQL(not necessary efficient can be:)

```
select
  id, type, birthday
from animals
  left join
  (select type, min(birthday) min_birthday
  from animals
  group by type) a 
     on a.type=animals.type and a.min_birthday = animals.birthday
where a.type is null;
```

For best efficiency you can use an analytical function:

```
select id, type, birthday
from(
    select
      id, 
      type, 
      birthday, 
      row_number() over (partition by type order by birthday) as rnk
    from animals
) a
where rnk >=2
```

For more examples with analytical functions, you can read this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0401kuznetsov/index.html)

Comment: Your first query would return nothing, I believe, if `ID` is the table's primary key. But your second one should work well.

Comment: You're right, thanks, I've put another pure SQL solution instead.

Comment: Will DB/2 require an alias on the derived table in the second one?

Comment: @muistooshort I don't know and I don't have DB2 at hand. However, I think is better to put it. Just two seconds...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! We are using the 2nd solution mentioned in the above post now.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can do:

```
select
  id, type, birthday
from (
    select
      id, type, birthday,
      row_number() over (partition by type order by birthday asc) r
    from
      animals
) q
where r > 1
```

The row_number() functions is [rumoured](http://db2nerd.blogspot.com/2008/08/be-smart-get-row-number.html) to work also in DB2, but I don't know under which circumstances/versions.

Comment: as can be seen in my response, in 2004 they existed.(see the article)

Answer (score 1):

The `exists` variant:

```
select id, type, birthday
from animals a
where exists (select null from animals e
              where e.type = a.type and e.birthday < a.birthday)
```

(Edited, following comments.)

Comment: This would return precisely what should be omitted. That is, it would be a correct answer with the inverted condition.

Comment: The OP seems to be looking for, by their own words, *‘a way of grouping the entries and then removing the first entry from each group’*. I understood *the first entry* as *the earliest entry*, so the earliest entries should not be returned, which, in turn, means only records for which earlier records exist should be returned.

Comment: @AndriyM: You are right, of course - answer corrected accordingly.

Comment: yes, Andriy you're right :) I would want to remove the earliest entry.